# Cannot use local variable DateTime before it is declared?

Tags: c#, datetime, compiler-errors

I want to get current DateTime in Console application in Main method, but I get compiler error "can not use local variable DateTime before it is declared". Below is the part of the code...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
       StringBuilder RequestString = new StringBuilder();
       string MachineID = "17";
       DateTime CT = DateTime.Now;
       string DateTime = CT.ToShortDateString();
       RequestString.Append(MachineID);
       RequestString.Append("|");
       RequestString.Append(DateTime);
       RequestString.Append("|");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change:

```
string DateTime = CT.ToShortDateString();
```

to:

```
string dateTime = CT.ToShortDateString();
```

you cannot use `DateTime` as variable name.

EDIT:
as [@user2864740 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088515/cannot-use-local-variable-datetime-before-it-is-declared#comment31720332_21088537) error is because variable `DateTime` is shadowing `DateTime` type and compiler thinks that OP is calling property `Now` on string variable `DateTime`

Comment: Nit: `DateTime` *is* a valid variable name, even if ill-advised. The problem here is that the variable shadows the Type in the expression `DateTime.Now` (but using the fully-qualified type name would also work, even if ill-advised).

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
string DateTime = CT.ToShortDateString();
```

you haven't given it a local variable name like:

```
string ctShortDate =  CT.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using DateTime as a variable name?
I dont think that is a good practice.

```
DateTime CT = DateTime.Now;
string currentdate = CT.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannet declare `DateTime` in the same line that you are using the class `DateTime`, the class is shadowing the variable name that you had picked.

You can change by the variable name to dateTime (for example) everywhere that you use, than will compile and run. Try to use this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder RequestString = new StringBuilder();
    string MachineID = "17";
    DateTime CT = DateTime.Now;
    string dateTime = CT.ToShortDateString();
    RequestString.Append(MachineID);
    RequestString.Append("|");
    RequestString.Append(dateTime);
    RequestString.Append("|");
}
```